# Is there a way to run multiple processes on two different cores in python at the same time?

Tags: python, multithreading, process, multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I am building a app using tkinter and customtkinter. I want it to update the screen every single second but every 3 seconds I want it to get the price of certain stocks that are in a list of stocks.txt than I want it to report that data to a table which is in datarows.txt and update that table based on the current price of the stock. Since the screen is updating every second I want it to check the table every second and see what it says the current price of the stock is and set it on the screen as that. I have it working exactly as it should however every 3 seconds when it goes to yahoo finance to check the prices of the stocks, it lags the program making it unusable for about a second or two while it checks the data. Heres all the code:

```
from tkinter import END
import customtkinter
from PIL import Image
import time
from yahoo_fin import stock_info as si
import datetime
import subprocess
from multiprocessing import Process


customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("Dark")  # Modes: "System" (standard), "Dark", "Light"
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")  # Themes: "blue" (standard), "green", "dark-blue"



class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        # Code for creating window
    #
    #

        def Refresher():
            lst = [("STOCK:", "PRICE:", "BUY/SELL:", "UP CONFIDENCE:", "DOWN CONFIDENCE:", "ACCURACY:"),
                   ("", "", "", "", "", "")]            
            with open("datarows.txt", "r") as data:
                data = data.readlines()
            for line in data:
                lists = []
                if len(line) > 10:
                    line = line.split(", ")
                    for string in line:
                        string = string.split("=")[1]
                        lists.append(string)
                    line = tuple(lists)
                    lst.append(line)
            total_row = len(lst)
            total_column = len(lst[0])
            for i in range(total_row):
                for j in range(total_columns):
                    self.e = customtkinter.CTkEntry(self.tabview.tab("Trading"))

                    self.e.grid(row=i, column=j, ipadx=50)
                    self.e.insert(END, lst[i][j])
            self.after(1000, Refresher)
        Refresher()

    def freshfit(self):
        global lst
        global total_rows
        global total_columns
        lst = [("STOCK:", "PRICE:", "BUY/SELL:", "UP CONFIDENCE:", "DOWN CONFIDENCE:", "ACCURACY:"),
               ("", "", "", "", "", "")]
        with open("datarows.txt", "r") as dat:
            dat = dat.readlines()
        for line in dat:
            thelist = []
            if len(line) > 10:
                line = line.split(", ")
                for strings in line:
                    string = strings.split("=")[1]
                    thelist.append(strings)
                line = tuple(thelist)
                lst.append(line)

        # find total number of rows and columns in list
        total_rows = len(lst)
        total_columns = len(lst[0])
        joe = []
        with open("stocks.txt", "r") as yeeter:
            yeet = yeeter.readlines()
            for line in yeet:
                line = line.strip("\n")
                stock = line
                with open("datarows.txt", "r") as dats:
                    daters = dats.readlines()
                    jake = []
                    for jim in daters:
                        jake.append(jim)
                        if stock in jim:
                            for bob in jake:
                                if stock in bob:
                                    live_prices = si.get_live_price(stock)
                                    bob = bob.split(", ")
                                    bob[1] = f"price={round(live_prices, 2)}"
                                    bob = ", ".join(bob)
                                    joe.append(str(bob) + "\n")
        with open("datarows.txt", "w") as writs:
            writs.write("")
        with open("datarows.txt", "a") as apens:
            for parts in joe:
                parts.strip("[[\n]]")
                apens.write(str(parts))
                lst.append(parts)
        self.after(3000, self.freshfit)



lst = [("STOCK:", "PRICE:", "BUY/SELL:", "UP CONFIDENCE:", "DOWN CONFIDENCE:", "ACCURACY:"),
                   ("", "", "", "", "", "")]
with open("datarows.txt", "r") as datas:
    datas = datas.readlines()
for line in datas:
    list = []
    if len(line) > 10:
        line = line.split(", ")
        for thestring in line:
            thestring= thestring.split("=")[1]
            list.append(thestring)
        line = tuple(list)
        lst.append(line)
# find total number of rows and columns in list
total_rows = len(lst)
total_columns = len(lst[0])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    p1 = Process(target=app.freshfit())
    p1.start()
    app.mainloop()
```

So I tried using multiprocessing as you can see to update the freshfit function independently but it still lags the program. The freshfit function is the one that grabs the stock data and inserts it into the table in datarows.txt and the nested function is the one that checks and updates the screen every second. I also do realize that my code is somewhat sloppy. I believe the issue is that even with multiprocessing its running the program on the same core. I have a 8 core cpu and I believe that since its running on the same core, it lags the whole program no matter what. I have tried understanding multithreading and multiprocessing.pool which I have not had success on meaning I either can't find the correct way to implement them or they aren't whats going to fix this problem. Any ideas?

EDIT: The stocks.txt file is just a list of stocks so each line is a different stock ticker such as aapl, spy, pep, etc and nothing else on that line and for right now the stocks.txt file has 7 stocks in it. The datarows.txt file has 3 rows right now just for testing purposes but I will eventually add all the stocks in there. This is what one of those lines looks like:
stock=aapl, price=186.96, buy/sell=neutral, upconfidence=85, downconfidence=15, accuracy=75
the stocks.txt file does not change that stays absolute however the datarows.txt file stays the same except for the price is updated in real time based on what the actual current price of that stock is. The program does this however lags the tkinter window too everytime it does.

Comment: Sorry, I read `sss` and  `ssss` everywhere, and I'll immediately leave due to that. Give your variables meaningful names. Good luck.

Comment: Fixed that. I told you the code was sloppy, not having to think about variable names lets me focus on the function of the program.

Comment: Typically, the opposite is the case. At least that's what I find with my students. They use wrong, misleading, sloppy or single character variable names and thus confuse themselves.

Comment: Why/what are you writing to files on disk? What volume and type of data are you retrieving from Yahoo Finance?

Comment: Well I am trying to get the current stock price for every stock in the stocks.txt list than I have in the datarows.txt file a list that includes each stock, its price, and a couple of other factors that I will include in my program. I am using the txt file to update the current price of the stock than using the nested function refresher trying to read that file and update it on the screen It all works however it is very slow because every time it checks yahoo finance for the stock price it stops the tkinter window for about a second to download that data Im trying to download it simultaneously

Comment: If you are fetching prices from Yahoo and displaying them on the screen, why do you write them to disk? Just keep them in RAM. Have you timed how long a query to Yahoo takes?

Comment: I am writing to disk so I can then call it and display it in the table. I have attempted using the program without calling real time stock data and just changing the txt file and it works in real time and without the yahoo finance call there is no lag at all meaning it has to be the reason for the lag

Comment: Mmm... how many lines are in `datarows.txt`, what do the first few look like, and do they change while the program is running? Same 3 questions for `stocks.txt`. Six answers please - not in *"Comments"* but by clicking [edit].

Comment: I see a big problem with your tkInter code: the function Refresher() runs once per second, and each time it runs you create a new bunch of CTkEntry widgets.  You grid them over top of the last bunch, so the old ones are not visible on the screen.  But they are still there, consuming resources but contributing nothing.  This program will eventually crash.  It is not the correct way to write a GUI program.  Try creating the widgets once, at the beginning, and updating the information in them rather than making new widgets every time.